# Сравнение элементов массива с выводом диапазона индексов, Java

Tags: java, массивы

Дан массив интов (ну, вернее двухмерный , но не суть) , нужно найти соответствия с числом поиска и вывести индексы в зависимости от последовательности совпадений диапазоном(если подряд есть совпадения) и/или одиночным индексом через "," если в соседних ячейках нет совпадений:

например: 
cравниваем с единицей: дан массив [7] { 1,1,1,0,2,1,3} вывод должен быть [ 0-2 , 4 ]

пользоватся можно только простейшими циклами и систем аутом... без сортировки без хешей без стрингов без коллекций

есть идеи ?  хэлп))

Так как размерность матрицы должна быть изменяемой и работать на любых рандомах, Наваял пока вот это:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Random;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int[][] arr = new int[4][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(4);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    int equalValue = 1;   //тут подставляем число с которым нужно сравнить
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Line " + (i+1) + ": ");
        outerLoop:
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == equalValue) {
                System.out.print("[" + j);
                if (j == (arr[i].length )) {
                    System.out.print("]");
                    break outerLoop;
                } else {
                    temp = 0;
                for (int x = j; x < arr[i].length; x++) {
                    if (arr[i][x] == equalValue) {
                        temp++;
                    } else {
                        temp = temp + 0;
                    }
                }
                    if (temp == 1) {
                        System.out.print("]");
                        //System.out.println();
                        break outerLoop;
                    } else {
                                    // Тут у меня уже отсечена/закрыта проверка на одиночные совпадения,
                                    // Есть флаг что множественные совпадения присутсвуют (temp>1)
                                    // Есть количество совпадений в подмассиве (value of (temp - 1))
                }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

И дальше уперся в непонимание как заставить "пропустить" индексы внутри диапазона, если он больше 2х. И при этом должно быть ОДНО "тирэ".

зы: это лаболаторная...

зызы: возможно я зациклился и пошел "не тудой" ?? буду рад и благодарен не готовому решению, но проверенному совету...

Comment: елементы) класс!

Comment: ну... больше на редактирование сообщения смотрелось) че уж..) подправил)

Answer (score 2):

вот такая штука вышла в результате...

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите необходимое число строк массива");
    int massWidth = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Введите необходимую длинну столбцов массива");
    int massDepth = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Введите число, это будет диапазон возможных значений для заполнения матрицы");
    int rn = sc.nextInt();
    int[][] arr = new int[massWidth][massDepth];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(rn);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Матрица имеет такой вид :");
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Введите число для поиска от "+0+" до "+rn);
    int equalValue = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Результат :");
    int temp;
    int flag = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Line " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        outerLoop:
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == equalValue) {
                System.out.print("[" + j);
                if (j == (arr[i].length)) {
                    System.out.print("]");
                    break outerLoop;
                } else {
                    temp = 0;
                    for (int x = j; x < arr[i].length; x++) {
                        if (arr[i][x] == equalValue) {
                            temp++;
                        } else {
                            temp = temp + 0;
                        }
                    }
                    if (temp == 1) {
                        System.out.print("]");
                        break outerLoop;
                    } else {
                        j++;
                        while (temp > 1){
                            if (flag <0 && arr[i][j]==equalValue){
                                flag = 1;
                            }
                            if (flag<0 && arr[i][j]!=equalValue){
                                flag = 1;
                                System.out.print(",");
                            }
                            if (flag >=0 && (arr[i][j]!=equalValue)){
                                while (arr[i][j]!=equalValue){
                                    j=j+1;
                                }
                                temp = temp -1;
                                System.out.print(j++);
                                flag =-1;
                            }
                            if (flag >=0 && (arr[i][j]==equalValue)){
                                while (arr[i][j]==equalValue){
                                    j= j+1;
                                    temp =temp -1;
                                    if (j==arr[i].length){
                                        break ;
                                    }
                                }
                                System.out.print("-"+(j-1));
                                flag = -1;
                            }
                            else {
                                flag = -1;
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.print("]");
                        break outerLoop;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Заводим переменную start, обозначающую индекс начала серии нужных чисел. В неактивном состоянии она равна -1.

```
если (start<0) и нужное число:
    start = i
если (start >=0) и (ненужное число или конец массива):
    если не первый раз:
        выводим запятую
    если (i-1 == start):
       выводим start
    иначе:
       выводим start - i-1
    start = -1
```

Comment: если (i-1 == start):
       выводим start    вот это место честно говоря не понял ... .

Comment: Это означает, что длина серии 1 (i-текущий индекс  в цикле), и выводим как одиночный индекс, а не диапазон

Comment: тьху.. а я мозг слома что за "минус один"...  патамуша при выпадании совпадения в [0][0] оно стучится к индексу -1 массива.. соотв експешины кидает на аутофбонд..  а вообще стройненько получилось. спасибо

Comment: А не должно быть такого совпадения - перед строкой start ведь выставляется в -1, т.е. на нулевом индексе серия может только начаться.

Comment: у меня серия не начинается если "temp >1" от туда плясал, и вот зациклился чтото... недодумал что еще один флажок завести можно/нужно)